# How to represent hierarchy in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, database-design, orm, sqlalchemy

I need to represent hierarchy of geographical objects in my database. Each object have a name and geographical coordinates (lat/lon).

The **1st level** of hierarchy may be one of two possible values: **Marine** | **Terrastiaral**.

**2nd level** (for **Marine**) may be Seas | Rivers.
**3rd level** (for **Seas**) consists of all possible Sea names (e.g. Baltic Sea).

**Additionally**, on **3rd level** I probably want to **link each Sea/River with ocean** it relates to, all **Rivers** should be additionally linked with some **Sea** it relates to.
There are also **4th, 5th and 6th** levels of hierarchy which are smaller types of objects.

**Important:** any combination of [3, 4, 5, 6] levels may be skipped in this type of hierarchy, i.e. we could have levels (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) or (1, 2, 3) or (1, 2, 3, 5).

Also, I will be using sqlalchemy **ORM** for object representation in my application.

Should I use different tables for different hierarchy levels with foreign keys for parent nodes?
For skipped levels we could use virtual nodes for each hierarchy path.

Should I make an unified table for all nodes and store its level as integer value, with FK for parents (i.e. adjacency list structure) ?

What are the pros and cons of each method?

Who have other ideas (taking into account all constraints)?

Comment: Do you want to store different things about each level in the hierarchy, or just the name and lat/long?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are going to do with the data. Your separate tables approach works well for certain kinds of uses.

If you go with a unified table,  there are two approaches you could take. The first is an adjacency list model. The adjacency list model in a relational schema doesn't look the same way it does in an object world.

The second is a nested set model. [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). The first is easier to update while the second is easier to use for complex queries, like finding a given subtree.

Answer (score 0):

the best table design i can think of is as below

```
table hirarchy

columns : hirarchyid | hirarchylevel



table hirarchy_possible_values

columns : possiblevalueid | possiblevalue | hirarchyid



table geo_object

columns : objectid | objectName| latitude | longitude  | hirarchyid | possiblevalueid
```

Comment: How is the parent-child relation is established in your proposed db schema?

Also, could you please explain what is the 'hirarchy_possible_values' for?